# Changing the language of an amsrefs generated bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, languages, amsrefs

*Using amsrefs for generating a bibliography, is there a way to change the language it uses, for instance, for separating multiple authors?*

Amsrefs does not seem to care about the language parameter given to babel.

I found this question asked several times on the web, but non of the answers given where satisfactory. Meaning they were saying: use bibtex or do ugly things by hand.

Comment: Does the `hyphenation` field of the `\bib` command (described on page 10 of the "User's Guide to the `amsrefs` Package") accomplish any of what you want?

Comment: @Phil: This does not seem to be what I want. If the language of my document is german, but the cited work's title is french, then the title should be hyphenated according to french hyphenation rules, but the authors' names should be separated by the german word for and.

Comment: OK, I just tried looking through `amsrefs.pdf`, the technical description of amsrefs. (At least the beginning is a lot more readable than I'd expected).  It looks like words like "and" are hard coded.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial solution, but: As I commented earlier, `amsrefs.pdf` seems to have the words like "and" hard coded.  I chased through the code a bit and found the `\newcommand` that defines `\PrintNames@a`, which has the word "and" appearing twice.  I put the following immediately after the `\usepackage{amsrefs}` command:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\PrintNames@a[4]{%
    \PrintSeries{\name}
        {#1}
        {}{ und \set@othername}
        {,}{ \set@othername}
        {,}{ und \set@othername}
        {#2}{#4}{#3}%
}
\makeatother
```

(that just changes each "and" to "und"), and the bibliography entries with multiple authors used "und" instead of "and".

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it's not only about the "and". For instance, "No." would have to be changed to "Nr.", and there are probably lots of further english bits showing up from time to time.